# WSO2EI - Outward SOAP call fails with hostname validation

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, opensaml, wso2-esb

**My Setup**

I am using WSO2EI version 6.4.0 to host my Rest API.

My Client --> WSO2EI --> Outside SOAP Calls

I do not have set up any mutual auth/keys etc. between WSO2EI and the outside servers.

**What I am doing**

When my client calls me(WSO2EI), I(WSO2EI) call other SOAP endpoints (different domains) and I(WSO2EI) am a client of these endpoints.

**The Issue**

A call from client(postman) --> WSO2EI --> OUT_SIDE_SOAP_END_POINT_1

whereas

another call from client(postman) --> WSO2EI --> OUT_SIDE_SOAP_END_POINT_2 does not.

However, a direct call from client(postman) --> OUT_SIDE_SOAP_END_POINT_2 works

**The Exception Stack**

```
[PassThroughMessageProcessor-1]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://vsb.nrt.unabdev.sprint.com/services/CloudService]
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:385)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:90)
#
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.DefaultEndpoint.send(DefaultEndpoint.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:119)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:358)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:426)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:113)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**What I have done and how they have faired**

1. Setting System Property[ignoreHostnameVerification] on integrator.sh

`-Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true` Same Exception

2. Setting System Property[hostnameVerifier & disableHostnameVerification] on integrator.sh

```
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll \
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true \
```

This did not work either.

Since the direct call from pos tman to OUT_SIDE_SOAP_END_POINT_2 works, I think OUT_SIDE_SOAP_END_POINT_2 is open and I should not have to do any settings on my WSO2EI instance.

Any thoughts and pointers are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination worked. This allowed for the Apache HTTP client to take over from SAML. However, then I had to add the certificate into the client trust store.

```
-Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true \
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true \
```

This solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace, you seem to be using a Call mediator in blocking mode. There seems to an issue already reported with regards to Blocking transport. https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/1501

Can you try out the workaround suggested in the issue?

> As a workaround for this, we can disable switching to opensaml http
>   client by setting rampart.axiom.parser.pool=false in a server start
>   up. So removing from the backlog